# Real TIme Image Processing (OCR)

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, ocr, augmented-reality

I am planing to develop an app like [Word Lens](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/word-lens/id383463868?mt=8). Can any one suggest a good library that I can use? or any one explain technology behind the Word Lens App? is it reel time image matching or OCR? I know some image processing library like OpenCv, tesseract...Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm one of the creators of Word Lens.  Although there are some OCR libraries out there (like tesseract), we decided to make our own in order to get better results and performance.  Our general algorithm goes like this:

1. copy the image from the camera and get its grayscale component
2. level out the image so the text stands out clearly against the background
3. draw boxes around things that look like characters & sentences
4. do OCR: match the pixels in each box against a database of characters -- this is actually pretty hard!
5. collect the characters into words, look up in a dictionary (this is hard too, because there will be mistakes in the OCR)
6. draw the results back onto the image

Image matching by itself is not good enough, because of the huge variety of fonts, words, and languages out there.

OpenCV is a great library to get up and running with, and to learn more about computer vision in general.  I would recommend building off their examples, and playing around there.  Have fun!

Comment: Would you get better results combining 4 and 5 in some way?  As a outsider to OCR, it seems to me that you've lost information by "5" that might be useful in difficult cases.

Comment: martin: quite right; e.g., a 'O' is very similar to an '0', or even an '8' and a 'B', so it helps to keep lists of possibilities, then trim them down in the following stages when more disambiguating information is available (a simple kind of feedback)

Comment: @jd. Thanks for your comment.. may I know how long it took for you to create Word Lens? would you please suggest good tutorials for OCR?

Comment: Word Lens took two people about two years to make (roughly).  i can't think of many good tutorials exactly, other than to recommend that you build a prototype.  if you can get a basic system working quickly, then you'll be prepared to ask the right kind of questions when you do more research.

Comment: @jd. thanks..I will be back after building a prototype...would you please connect me via gmail? my id is 2arshu@gmail.com?

Comment: @Ab'initio, I hope I've set you off in a good direction, and that others can benefit from my simple introduction to this problem, but I'll leave it at that for now.  Good luck to you!

Comment: @jd, Now I am able to detect characters with almost 60% of accuracy and able position them in the image. But now what matters is the accuracy, processing time and support for different fonts? Hope you will have a good advice for me in this area...Once again thanks for your kind support...