# Tesseract limitation for iPhone iso ? any other OCR engine for ios

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to use Tesseract for my iphone app for OCR, but its not recognise the low resolution image text, so whats the limitation of Tesseract OCR for iPhone SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract works great on iOS.  The hardest part is installation.

Here is a sample project that uses it on github:

https://github.com/AdamGluck/split

(Disclosure, this is a project I worked on for fun.  However, it implements tesseract for iOS.)

We used this framework:

https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios

I'll note that we got better results when we made the image a sharper black and white (in the project).  Although this was not that necessary to get good results.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [Real TIme Image Processing (OCR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656331/real-time-image-processing-ocr)

Abbyy cloud is an cloud service for doing OCR online.